# Float bug while refreshing a page in Chrome on Mac OS. Why?

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

Sometimes refreshing a page, floated left or right page elements renders wrong, jumping below their actual positions.
Able to reproduce this bug only using latest version of Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.8. 
Some screenshots:

Good: 
[image: Good]
Bad:
[image: Wrong]

Comment: I've noticed this on Webkit Nightlies, too. Mac 10.8

Comment: I see the same behavior in Chrome 23.0.1271.97. But it only occurs sometimes and is gone after a page refresh, so I don't know what bug to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the last element jumps to the bottom due to space constraints, my suggestion is to try giving each DIV inside the Div.Basket a border and check each div width, most probably you'll notice that the last element doesn't have enough space to fit inside the box, if this is the case then just reduce the width of any of the div's to make space.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent to "position:relative;" and the cross to "position:absolute; top:0; right:0;". It will keep the cross in the top corner of the parent.